# Find $\alpha$and $\beta$ $d(F(x,y))=(\frac{1}{x^2+2}+\frac{\alpha}{y})dx+(xy^\beta +1)dy$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$d(F(x,y))=(\frac{1}{x^2+2}+\frac{\alpha}{y})dx+(xy^\beta +1)dy$$
Find the alpha and beta for which the equation becomes exact and the next condition give is F(x,y)=0

I solved the equations using the relation $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$

the alpha value comes $$\alpha=-y^{\beta+2}$$
I plugged the value in the above equation and found the value of $\beta$ as $-y^3$
IS the value of the equation correct and I calculated the values by assuming the $dF(x,y)=0$
Is the assumption and the value correct?

Answer (score 0):

$$d(F(x,y))=(\frac{1}{x^2+2}+\frac{\alpha}{y})dx+(xy^\beta +1)dy$$
$$\begin{cases}
    \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{x^2+2}+\frac{\alpha}{y} \\
    \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} =xy^\beta +1\\
  \end{cases}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x\partial y} = -\frac{\alpha}{y^2} = y^\beta$$
Thus : 
$$\begin{cases}
    \alpha=-1 \\
    \beta=-2 \\
  \end{cases}$$
$$d(F(x,y))=(\frac{1}{x^2+2}-\frac{1}{y})dx+(xy^{-2}+1)dy$$
$F(x,y)=\int \frac{dx}{x^2+2}-\frac{x}{y}+f(y)= -x y^{-1}+y+g(x)$
$$\begin{cases}
    f(y)=y +c\\
    g(x)=\int \frac{dx}{x^2+2} +c\\
  \end{cases}$$
$$F(x,y)= -\frac{x}{y}+y+\int \frac{dx}{x^2+2}+c$$